# Change VS2017 default New Project location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to change the default path when creating a new project in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I found how to do it - from Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Locations->Projects location and enter the custom folder there.

[image]

Tbh, I prefer the Qt Creator approach where it just remembers the last change to the Default workspace.

Answer (score 2):

For **macOS**:

Preferences > Projects > Load/Save and change the "Default Solution location".

[image]