# Visual Studio 2019 how to change the default location for source directory

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2019, default

Whenever I create new solutions or open a solution Visual Studio places them in my location "C:\Users\\Source\Repos".

I want to change this to a different drive as a default. I can do it manually each time opening a project, but that becomes time consuming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change VS2017 default New Project location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863277/change-vs2017-default-new-project-location)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change "Visual Studio 2017" folder location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703179/how-to-change-visual-studio-2017-folder-location)

Answer (score 5):

Settings are here Tools--> Options::Project And Solutions-->Locations